# Android Studio SDK is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, installation

I had a USB connection problem when I debug and updated BIOS then, the laptop had problem with drive so, I needed to recover it. So, I recovered it with removing all the applications and just kept my personal files.

And I downloaded and installed Android Studio again, and SDK missing problem occurred like below:

1. I can't see 'SDK' when I install Android Studio from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads). So, I can't select any.
   [image]
2. I tried with SDK Manager. I can't install any versions with "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date, or corupted." error.

[image]

3. I tried Update. But nothing changed. (Updated to 3.3.1, but failed to Sync SDKs ERROR.)
4. Some people on Stack-overflow suggested to download SDK separately, but their links just show Android Studio installer, which I already installed. Maybe the links were so old.
5. "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" does not exists.
   [image]
6. I uninstalled Android Studio include User setting and reinstalled it.(There is no such thing that I can select previous version kind of thing.) But the result is the same.

Comment: try to reinstall Android IDE and don't select the pervious version after that download sdk

Comment: There is no such thing like that when I install it. But I uninstalled it include User settings and reinstalled it. But the same result.

Comment: don't select user setting

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/#command-tools

Comment: download SDK from this link and place into your location

Comment: Well, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did it work? If yes, how?

Comment: @RC0993 I answered. Please check it out.

Comment: Hey @c-an I reinstalled the (fresh copy of) Android studio and found it working. It automatically chose the required resources to get installed (this time).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem with connecting `android-sdk` folder in `C drive`.

I reinstalled my OS. But hopefully, I kept my personal folders. So, I could find that folder.

However, If you don't have SDK folder, you may need to install SDK by yourself.

Answer (score 15):

**TL;DR This is sometimes caused by Windows registry settings retained with the current AndroidStudio project. To fix, just startup Android Studio and then close the current project (`File -> Close Project`). If this was the problem, AS will now go into a long update and restart cycle to repair itself, but will end with success.**

**I also recommend that you then change AS settings to not open the last project on Startup (`Settings -> System Settings -> Reopen projects on startup`)**

---

Windows 10, Android Studio v3.6 and v4.0.

This one drove me nuts! I had the same problem - my SDK seemed to be corrupt so I did a full Uninstall (v3.6) and Install (4.0) of Android Studio and when Android Studio started up I got the same message `Android SDK is missing`.

The `SDK Manager` in `Tools` wasn't working.

I went to the link and there was nothing to download the SDK. So I installed the file which looked a bit like the SDK, `commandlinetools-win-6514223_latest.zip`, unzipped, and then tried to use the missing SDK dialog to include it in AS, and no joy.

BUT - I noticed that after an uninstall and fresh install Android Studio still came up with the last project I was working on so I guessed it must be something in the windows registry (rather than AS settings). I closed that project and AS suddenly popped up a dialog to install the SDK!

After a big download and install, Android Studio returned with the SDK (and SDK manager) all functioning!

**So - just startup Android Studio and then close the current project (`File -> Close Project`)!**

---

How I did a complete re-install.

Uncheck the "Keep Settings" (or similar) option in the Uninstall dialog, but export your settings first (File -> Export Settings). I found it easy to: Export settings; Complete Uninstall; Download and Install; Import Settings;. But, or course, there were several massive downloads. Still don't know why the last open file came up after the fresh install. It's probably in the registry, so, if there are still problems then you'll have to clear AS from the registry as well. Which sounds painful.

Comment: Thanks man. That was exactly what i needed!

Comment: So incredibly frustrating. Using the SDK manager from the project window puts you in a loop of trying to download the SDK and being told the SDK does not exist or is corrupted 

Thank you for the solution that actually works!

Answer (score 0):

If android sdk is deleted, go to :
SDK manager -> edit -> next ..

Answer (score 0):

My android SDK was corrupted (AS messed up and deleted some files), so I needed a full reinstallation

1. Go to corrupted sdk folder and delete it (backup, just in case). You can check the path with `echo $ANDROID_HOME`. I have no clue for windows users.
2. Open AS Giraffe. This prompts a nice wizard that isn't present in Flamingo.
3. SDK is installed

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same isssue, but it got solved when i closed the Application from the Task Manager and Restarted the Application, It popped up an installion window to install the necessary File in the SDK folder.
P.S. : I freshly installed the Android Studio with no previous files or project on the System.